# Port open for memcache in aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, memcached

Hi I'm running an aws ec2 instance with Drupal 6.

I plan on installing memcached on this server. One requirement is to open up port 11211 which is default port for memcached

I want to know in aws ec2 instance how to open incoming and outgoing traffic for port 11211? Do I need to open this port for incoming and outgoing traffic?

Secondly how do I secure the aws setup so only my ec2 can access 11211 port?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Ec2 within a VPC ? or is it classic EC2 ?

You need to make open ports on security groups and Network acl's. 
If you are new to AWS , you should first understand the NACL and Security group's and setup security in your environment.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: It's a classic ec2 so incoming and outgoing traffic? How do i set it up so that only my ec2 is allowed

Comment: Check security group assigned for the EC2 instance and edit the rules

Comment: So can i set up security group rule for source ip being the private IP address of the ec2 instance?

Comment: Since its a classic EC2 ..your EC2 instance is running inside a default vpc . This vpc is connected to internet via IGW (internet gateway) . Within this vpc you can create your own web security group, db security group . and internally you can allow/disallow traffice based on SG name . you dont have to get to too granular. However you can also specify private ip range and set up rules. .http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/images/classiclink-security-groups-example-diagram.png